# Matlab BioGraph can't set node sizes for unconnected nodes

Tags: matlab, graph

I've created a [`biograph` object](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/biograph.html) on matlab which has already turned autosizing off. And I used

```
set(my_biograph.Nodes(i),'size', [MysizeX MysizeY])
```

to set the sizes of the nodes.

However, the isolated nodes that don't have any connections will tend to get the size equal to that of the nodes I've assigned the largest size to.

Any ideas? Here is some test code:

```
cm   = [0 1 1 0 0; 1 0 0 1 0; 1 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0];
ids  = {'M30931', 'L07625', 'K03454', 'M27323', 'M15390'};
test = biograph (cm, ids,        ...
         'LayoutType', 'radial', ...
         'Scale', 1,             ...
         'LayoutScale', 2,       ...
         'NodeAutoSize', 'off');

set (test.Nodes(5), 'Shape', 'Circle');
set (test.Nodes(4), 'Shape', 'Circle');
view (test);
set (test.Nodes(4), 'size', [100, 100]);
```

The last command will change the sizes of two nodes!

Comment: Provide an executable example. See [MCVE]

Comment: @SardarUsama just updated with an example

Comment: I can confirm this. Seems like a bug. Interestingly, if you do this graphically you can change size of one circle without changing the other. Also, when you select a circle once, after that the command seems to work as expected. EDIT: Sometimes. Sometimes it doesn't. Seems like a bug. I'd report it to matlab.